# Form inside a draggable wrapper - mobile not allowing form element selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mobile

As the title says, my form is inside a draggable (jQuery UI) wrapper. On a PC I can select the input fields in the form just fine but on my iPhone (tested a couple versions and an Android as well) I can't directly tap the input field to select it. If I tap the field label it doesn't select the field either, but if I tap the hell out of it eventually it'll select the field.

Needless to say, that's not intuitive for users so I need a way to fix the functionality of the form inside the draggable container.

Abbreviated code:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="postal_code">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

$('.footer').draggable({...});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o4xp0t64/7/ (updated)

I'm using:

- jQuery 1.10.2
- jQuery UI 1.10.2
- jQuery Migrate 1.2.1
- jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.3

Note: This appears to work in the jsfiddle for Androids using Chrome. My dev site (not accessible to unauthorized external vistiors) behaves as described on all mobile devices we've tested.

Comment: Works fine on Chrome for Android (Samsung Galaxy S5).

Comment: I'm not sure what was used on the Android I had a friend use to check it. But when I tried Chrome on my iPhone 5 it reacts the same as described. When my friend gets back from lunch I'll check with him to see what he was using.